# Creating first user using cURL returns code 403 "Access not configured"

Tags: curl, google-cloud-sql

I try to create the first user for my instance of a Google Cloud SQL server.

The cURL-query I use is:

```
curl -X POST --header "Authorization: Bearer MY TOKEN" --header "Content-Type: application/json" https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/MY PROJECT/instances/MY INSTANCE/users --data "{'host': '%', 'name': 'MY USERNAME', 'password': 'MY PASSWORD'}"
```

The Google Cloud SQL API is activated for my project.

As response message I get:

```
"message": "Access Not Configured. Cloud SQL Administration API has not been used \in project 407408718192 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sqladmin/overview?project=4074087XXXXX then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."
```

The project ID I get back is not even my own.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?
Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: The project number that appears in the error message corresponds to the project that owns the access token. Did you obtain the access project from the same project that you enabled the Cloud SQL Admin API? Note that this is not necessarily the same project that owns the Cloud SQL instances you are trying to manage.

Comment: That was indeed the problem, thank you very much.
On the playground I was able to choose to use my own oAuth Credentials and with those it worked+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in Juan Enrique Muñoz Zolotoochin's comment I needed to use my own credentials in the oAuth playground (Top right corner, the cogwheel)

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. I tried what you said and I get a 400 error page saying: Error: redirect_uri_mismatch. Did you get this as well?

Comment: Sorry that did not happen for me. Can you describe exactly what you are doing and trying to do?

Comment: I got it to work, I was just trying to generate an Auth Bearer token for a curl request but I was using the wrong service account. Thanks!